# What does "inside references" mean?

Tags: expressions

> All commencement speakers who shamelessly pander with cheap, inside references designed to get childish applause, will be forced to apologize

It's from Conan's commencement speech and I'm not sure about "inside references" here. I'm assuming it means "a person who gives you a reference, for example when you are applying for a job" but I'm not sure...

Comment: What research did you do? When asking about a specific word, look it up in a dictionary and carefully examine **all** the definitions to see if any fit. Here, [Lexico adjective sense 2](https://www.lexico.com/definition/inside) fits: "Known by someone within the organisation" — an *inside reference* refers to something only someone inside the organisation would know.

Comment: I know it's actually less common, but I'd much prefer *cheap, **insider** references* unless *"**inside**"* is explicitly set off with "scare quotes" to help the reader parse the text.

Answer (score 0):

OED

> **Inside**:
>
> **B** *Adjective:*
>
> **d. figurative. Coming from ‘the inside’; inner; not generally available.**
>
> 1888   Daily Inter Ocean (Chicago) 20 Feb. (Farmer)   A secret service officer..claims to have inside information as to the facts in the case.
>
> 1973   D. Lees Rape of Quiet Town i. 10   As soon as they hear I'm from the Pictorial they'll fall over themselves to give me the inside gen [=information].

An *inside reference* is thus a reference which refers to/mentions a particular event, thing or person that only those inside the profession or organisation will be aware of.

Comment: The OP seems to be unfamiliar with the with the relevant meaning of *reference* (although explaining that would probably be off-topic, as a matter of general reference).